# Auto moderating comments with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a requirement to have comments on an application auto-moderated for obscenities etc.  There will still be a real world moderating looking at comments, but they want to filter out the really bad stuff automatically.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use something like [Akismet](http://akismet.com/).  Last I checked, it's the thing WordPress uses to prevent comment spam.  It's pretty straightforward, too.

Here are a couple links:

- [Ryan Bates over at Railscasts
  (always excellent, but a little old
  so may not current with Rails 3
  though)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/65-stopping-spam-with-akismet)
- [Another tutorial on
  using Akismet in Rails](http://soakedandsoaped.com/articles/2006/10/01/how-to-protect-a-rails-application-against-spam-with-akismet)

Here's a gem/plugin:  [Rakismet](http://github.com/joshfrench/rakismet)

As for profanity instead of general spam, you might want something like [WebPurify](http://www.webpurify.com/) (first one I found).  You can hack your own together by blacklisting profane words and using Ruby's elegant string handling to replace/filter them, but that would probably be a never ending battle against 1337 speak and stuff like that.  Plus it's probably better practice to outsource something like that, if possible.

Comment: re profanity: beware the clbuttic mistakes - there's a lot of false positives, as citizens of Scunthorpe, England found out, amongst others.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-moderation for obcenities is always going to give problems, as shown by Jeff Atwoods Post about it: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html).

Now, on the other hand, actively filtering Spam using an automatic (third party) text analysis tools is certainly an viable option ( [Mollom](http://mollom.com) for example, which also have a [ruby plugin](http://mollom.rubyforge.org/) )

Answer (score 1):

You can try fu-fu, not perfect but will filter out a lot.

http://github.com/adambair/fu-fu